# Finding cumulative sum and then average the values in R

Tags: r, matrix, cumsum

I want to compute cumulative sum for the first `(n-1) columns`(if we have `n` columns matrix) and subsequently average the values. I created a sample matrix to do this task. I have the following matrix

```
ma = matrix(c(1:10), nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
ma
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

I wanted to find the following

```
ans = matrix(c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5), nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
ans
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    3    4    5
```

The following are my `r` function.

```
ColCumSumsAve <- function(y){
  for(i in seq_len(dim(y)[2]-1)) {
    y[,i] <- cumsum(y[,i])/i
  }
}
ColCumSumsAve(ma)
```

However, when I run the above function its not producing any output. Are there any mistakes in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just add a line with `y` below your for loop, but still in the `ColCumSumsAve` function, you'll get output because you'll explicitly return the modified matrix. The output doesn't match your desired results though, and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how they're supposed to be calculated.

Comment: @Marius, for instance, in the resulting matrix the first column is the same as the input matrix of the first column. But the column 2, the `[1,2]` element is `{1+3)/2 = 2` and `[2,2] element is `(2+4)/2=3` and `[1,3]` is `(1+3+5)/3=3` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k <- t(apply(ma,1,cumsum))[,-ncol(k)]
for (i in 1:ncol(k)){
  k[,i] <- k[,i]/i
}
k
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

There were several mistakes.

**Solution**

This is what I tested and what works:

```
colCumSumAve <- function(m) {
  csum <- t(apply(X=m, MARGIN=1, FUN=cumsum))
  res <- t(Reduce(`/`, list(t(csum), 1:ncol(m))))
  res[, 1:(ncol(m)-1)]
}
```

Test it with:

```
> colCumSumAve(ma)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    3    4    5
```

which is correct.

Explanation:

```
colCumSumAve <- function(m) {
  csum <- t(apply(X=m, MARGIN=1, FUN=cumsum)) # calculate row-wise colsum
  res <- t(Reduce(`/`, list(t(csum), 1:ncol(m))))
  # This is the trickiest part.
  # Because `csum` is a matrix, the matrix will be treated like a vector 
  # when `Reduce`-ing using `/` with a vector `1:ncol(m)`.
  # To get quasi-row-wise treatment, I change orientation
  # of the matrix by `t()`. 
  # However, the output, the output will be in this transformed
  # orientation as a consequence. So I re-transform by applying `t()`
  # on the entire result at the end - to get again the original
  # input matrix orientation.
  # `Reduce` using `/` here by sequencial list of the `t(csum)` and
  # `1:ncol(m)` finally, has as effect `/`-ing `csum` values by their
  # corresponding column position.
  res[, 1:(ncol(m)-1)] # removes last column for the answer.
  # this, of course could be done right at the beginning,
  # saving calculation of values in the last column,
  # but this calculation actually is not the speed-limiting or speed-down-slowing step
  # of these calculations (since this is sth vectorized)
  # rather the `apply` and `Reduce` will be rather speed-limiting.
}
```

Well, okay, I could do then:

```
colCumSumAve <- function(m) {
  csum <- t(apply(X=m[, 1:(ncol(m)-1)], MARGIN=1, FUN=cumsum))
  t(Reduce(`/`, list(t(csum), 1:ncol(m))))
}
```

or:

```
colCumSumAve <- function(m) {
  m <- m[, 1:(ncol(m)-1)] # remove last column
  csum <- t(apply(X=m, MARGIN=1, FUN=cumsum))
  t(Reduce(`/`, list(t(csum), 1:ncol(m))))
}
```

This is actually the more optimized solution, then.

**Original Function**

Your original function makes only assignments in the `for`-loop and doesn't return anything.
So I copied first your input into a `res`, processed it with your `for`-loop and then returned `res`.

```
ColCumSumsAve <- function(y){
  res <- y
  for(i in seq_len(dim(y)[2]-1)) {
    res[,i] <- cumsum(y[,i])/i
  }
  res
}
```

However, this gives:

```
> ColCumSumsAve(ma)
     [,1] [,2]     [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1  1.5 1.666667 1.75    9
[2,]    3  3.5 3.666667 3.75   10
```

The problem is that the `cumsum` in matrices is calculated in column-direction instead row-wise, since it treats the matrix like a vector (which goes columnwise through the matrix).

**Corrected Original Function**

After some frickeling, I realized, the correct solution is:

```
ColCumSumsAve <- function(y){
  res <- matrix(NA, nrow(y), ncol(y)-1) 
  # create empty matrix with the dimensions of y minus last column
  for (i in 1:(nrow(y))) {           # go through rows
    for (j in 1:(ncol(y)-1)) {       # go through columns
      res[i, j] <- sum(y[i, 1:j])/j  # for each position do this
    }
  }
  res   # return `res`ult by calling it at the end!
}
```

with the testing:

```
> ColCumSumsAve(ma)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    3    4    5
```

Note: `dim(y)[2]` is `ncol(y)` - and `dim(y)[1]` is `nrow(y)` -
and instead `seq_len()`, `1:` is shorter and I guess even slightly faster.

Note: My solution given first will be faster, since it uses `apply`, vectorized `cumsum` and `Reduce`. - `for`-loops in R are slower.

Late Note: Not so sure that the first solution is faster. Since R-3.x it seems that `for` loops are faster. `Reduce` will be the speed limiting funtion and can be sometimes incredibly slow.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `rowMeans`:

```
nc <- 4
cbind(ma[,1],sapply(2:nc,function(x) rowMeans(ma[,1:x])))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it

```
> t(apply(ma, 1, function(x) cumsum(x) / 1:length(x)))[,-NCOL(ma)]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    3    4    5
```

This applies the `cumsum` function row-wise to the matrix `ma` and then divides by the correct length to get the average (`cumsum(x)` and `1:length(x)` will have the same length). Then simply transpose with `t` and remove the last column with `[,-NCOL(ma)]`.

The reason why there is no output from your function is because you aren't returning anything. You should end the function with `return(y)` or simply `y` as Marius suggested. Regardless, your function doesn't seem to give you the correct response anyway.